# How to remove get param on form submit?

Tags: html, forms, parameters, get, submit

Can you advice me how to remove get parameter (input text) without removing the value of the input or disabling it? Is this possible at all?

Comment: Can you post the reason why you want to remove the get?

Comment: I didn't express my self correct. I want to remove one of get query parameters

Answer (score 6):

Remove the name from the submit input.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to switch to the POST method when submitting your form. This way the parameters aren't passed by the Url anymore but rather in the HTTP header which is not visible.

Comment: This will break bookmarking, link sharing and all the other things that make GET useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can place the text field outside the form

OR

you could use `Javascript` and remove that particular parameter before sending the request.

The `javascript` method will give you more flexibility.

Comment: This violates the principle of progressive enhancement.

Comment: Yes, javascript is good idea. The system on which I'm working on is using jQuery, and tay to use the "submit(fnc)" function which callback function parameter is eventObject, but through this object 'm accessing only the eventTarget which is the form.